# setting up idle windows 10

Tags: python, python-idle

I have used idle before, but never set it up. my problem is actually getting a py file to work with. I don't actually know how to make one and it isn't an option when using save as on a text file. (only text file and all files(?) are put as options) I've attempted to open the py files already in the python folder but when selecting edit with idle I get prompted to pick what to open the file with and then if I click python nothing happens.

what am I missing?

Comment: What python version?

Comment: Questions about 'Edit with IDLE' in Windows Explorer pertain to Windows and the Python installer (which one did you use?) and don't actually involve IDLE itself until Windows properly tells python to run IDLE with a particular file.  Once Windows does so, there are no known issues.

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE's will allow you to save as .py, but the answer is  to save as "all files" then manually enter .py

ie. name your file file.py rather than the filename with no extension.

You should review this page:

[https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/bytes/start.html](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emitra/bytes/start.html)

especially "Writing Your First Python Program" and "Running Your First Program"

Comment: I have it saved as a py file now but it still doesn't open when I select open with idle

Comment: That should do it? What happens when you search IDLE in start menu?

Comment: it flashes a black window open for a split second and then it immediately closes

Answer (score 1):

If you select File => New and then File => Save as, the default will be to make it a .py file if you add no other extension.